# Can somebody assist with the following syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm new to the subject, I'm trying to set up account creation on a web, samp, but when I create the character it presents this error.

**1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Character,Password,Level,Gender,Age,Admin,Skin,FightStyle,registrado,Health,Cash' at line 1**

```
$GranaInicial = 0;
$NomeOOC = $_SESSION["MasterAccount"];
$Myid = $_SESSION["yourID"];

$hashedPassword_u = hash( 'whirlpool',$pers_senha);
$querycreateus = "INSERT INTO players (Character,Password,Level,Gender,Age,Admin,Skin,FightStyle,registrado,Health,Cash,LastLogin,pNomeOOC,pHealthMax,Story, Origin, MasterAccount) VALUES ('$pers_name','$hashedPassword_u','0','$pers_gender','$pers_idade','0','1','4','1','100','$GranaInicial','Nunca','$NomeOOC', '100', '$pers_story', '$pers_origem', '$Myid')";
$insertuserindb = mysql_query($querycreateus,$connectidb);
echo mysql_errno($connectidb) . ": " . mysql_error($connectidb) . "\n";
```

Someone help me please

Comment: You are using an insecure API, which was deprecated more years ago than I can remember

Answer (score 2):

Character is a reserved word in MySQL. Admin is a reserved word in some versions of MySQL. Escape them with back ticks.

```
... (`Character`,Password,Level,Gender,Age,`Admin`,Skin, ...
```